# Picard iteration, summation expression of IVP

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, summation

Given the following IVP:

$x' = 2tx^2, x(0) = 1$

Its first three Picard iterations are given by:

$x_0 = 1$

$x_1 = t^2 + 1$

$x_2 = \frac{1}{3} t^6 + t^4 + t^2 + 1$

Then the $n$th Picard iteration $x_n(t)$ has the form

$x_n(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{N_n} c_{k,n} t^{2k}$, where $c_{k,n} \geq$ depends on indices $k, n$.

1. What would be an explicit from for $N_n$? For the first three iterations we have $N_n$ given by 0, 1, and 3, but that doesnt help me.
2. How would one prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $c_{k,n} = 1$ if $0 \leq k \leq n$?
3. From (1) and (2), and $c_{k,n} \in [0,1]$ for $k>n$, follows that

$x_n(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{N_n} t^{2k} + z_n(t)$, with $z_n(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{N_n} c_{k,n} t^{2k}$.

How does one show that $lim_{n \to \infty} z_n(t) = 0$ for $|t| < 1$?

Comment: $x_2$ appears to be incomplete, it should have degree $6$?

Comment: $x_2 = \frac{1}{3} t^6 + t^4 + t^2 + 1$ is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct in view that the solution is $x=\frac{1}{1-t^2}=1+t^2+t^4+t^6+t^8+...$. In each iteration one more term should get its correct coefficient and stay that way in all further iterations.

Answer (score 1):

1. We can proceed by induction. Suppose $N_n = 2^n - 1$ (you can guess this formula when you realize that every time you integrate square of previous polynomial [degree doubles] multiplied by $t$).
   Then next iteration is
   $$
   1+\int_0^t2s\left(\sum_{k = 0}^{N_n}c_{k,n}s^{2k}\right)^2\operatorname d \!s
   = 1 + \int_0^t 2c_{N_n,n}^2 s^{4N_n + 1} + o(s^{4N_n + 1})\operatorname d\!s
   = c_{N_{n+1}, n+1}t^{4N_n + 2} + o(s^{4N_n + 2}).
   $$
   *I use little o notation here loosely (here at point at $\infty$; later at $0$), we must remember we are dealing with polynomials only.*
   By induction hypothesis, $4N_n + 2 = 4 \cdot(2^n - 1) + 2 = 2 \cdot (2^{n + 1}  -1)$, and therefore $N_{n+1} = 2^{n+1} - 1$.
2. Again, induction seems easy. Suppose that $c_{k, n} = 1$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$. Consider coefficient standing before $t^{2m}$ in $\left(\sum_{k = 0}^{N_n}c_{k,n}t^{2k}\right)^2$, wehre $0 \leq m \leq n$. We use Cauchy product formula to get
   $$
   \sum_{k = 0}^{m} 1 \cdot 1 = m + 1.
   $$
   Alternatively, we are just counting ways in which we can express $2m$ as sum of positive even summands, including zero. That is $(0, 2m), (2, 2m-2), \ldots (2m, 0)$. Therefore,
   $$
   1+\int_0^t2s\left(\sum_{k = 0}^{N_n}c_{k,n}s^{2k}\right)^2\operatorname d \!s
   = 1+\int_0^t 2\sum_{k = 0}^{n}(k+1)s^{2k+1} + o(s^{2n+1})\operatorname d \!s
   =\sum_{k = 0}^{n+1}t^{2k} + o(t^{2n+2})
   $$

At this point, I realized this is homework problem, so I let you finish yourself.

Comment: Why the $s$ in the integral? I'm assuming you plugged the sum into the integral equation, but the one I found is given by: $x_n (t) = 1 + \int_{0}^{t} 2t (x_{n-1})^2 ds$

Comment: It comes from integral equation equivalent to your differential equation $x(t)= 1+\int_0^t 2sx^2(s)\operatorname d\!s$. That is where Picard iterations come from...